# Sort an array of objects by number of occurrences and remove duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

`Model.find_by_tag_name("#foo")` returns an array with:

- 25 records with `tag_name = "#foo"`
- 40 records with `tag_name = "#foobar"`
- 15 records with `tag_name = "#foobarbaz"`

I want to count the number of times each unique `tag_name` showed up, sort the results by that count, then eliminate duplicates. The resulting order should be:

1. #foobar
2. #foo
3. #foobarbaz

Currently I'm doing something like this to get the uniques and a count:

```
counter = Hash.new(0)
uniques = results.each{|tag| counter[tag.tag_name] += 1 }.uniq{|tag| tag.tag_name }
```

The above makes `counter => {"#foo"=>25, "#foobar"=>40, "#foobarbaz"=>15}`.

Having retrieved, de-duped and counted the results, what approaches might I take to sorting the resulting array of unique tags(`uniques`) by the number of times they showed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"#foo"=>25, "#foobar"=>40, "#foobarbaz"=>15}.sort_by { |k, v| -v }.map(&:first)
```

Comment: I should have been more clear- I don't want to sort `counter`, but rather the array of unique results.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell did you even run the code? Ross’s first answer does return what you are looking for.